# Ionic/Angular - The Menu icon disappears for large screens

Tags: angular, iconic

The hamburger menu icon to toggle the side menu disappears for large screens. So the side menu pane stays open permanently. I was unable to get the menu icon on such screens so users can toggle on and off the side menu. I did not find the solution from previous queries, but found it in the documentation. May be someone will find it useful.
Solution: I was able to use the ion-split-pane property.

OR

See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See above - the answer is included. Code is below.

```
<ion-split-pane when="xl" contentId="main-content"> <!-- show the permanent left menu only for extra large screens-->
```

OR

```
<ion-split-pane when="(min-width: 4000px)" contentId="main-content"> <!-- show the permanent left menu only for basically all screens (except maybe big TVs)-->
```